# how to use a controlled component as a Control in react-redux-form?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, material-ui, react-redux-form

It is a bit complicated to explain but in short, I am trying to combine :

- [Material UI's Select field](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/select-field) with
- [React-redux-form's Control component](http://davidkpiano.github.io/react-redux-form/docs/api/Control.html)

I put the Select component in a Control:

```
                    <Control model=".month" component={CustomSelectComponent}
                        floatingLabelText="Month" /> <br />
```

Where the `CustomSelectComponent` is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'    
import SelectField from 'material-ui/SelectField'
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem'

class CustomSelectComponent extends Component {

    months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

    state = {
        value: ""
    };

    handleChange = (event, index, value) => {
        this.setState({ value });
        this.props.onChange(value);
    }

    render = () => {
        return (
            <SelectField
                floatingLabelText={this.props.floatingLabelText}
                value={this.state.value}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
            >
                {this.months.map(m => <MenuItem key={m} value={m} primaryText={m} />)}
            </SelectField>
        )
    }
}

export default CustomSelectComponent;
```

Now the issue is that when using the form for an EDIT action, the model has a value for the month, but it s not reflected in the view. The select component appears unfilled.

There is a spot-on explanation/warning on the documentation of the react-redux-form about this. (on [this page](https://davidkpiano.github.io/react-redux-form/docs/guides/custom-controls.html), scroll to 'Model and View Values')

But the example that is used is not a controlled component.

So i guess the question is :

**How could I map the viewModel to value in a controlled component?**

I hope it s clear, thanks for any help.